# I want to ... With you

Tags: particles, particle-と, particle-を

I want to say "I want to watch a movie with you"..

Can I say this?

あなたと映画を見るつもりです

Comment: つもり means "intention".

Answer (score 3):

> あなたと映画を見るつもりです。I plan to see a movie with you.

と is the right particle to use with あなた if you want to mean "with them", however, つもり　tends to mean "I plan to" , and not "I want to".

**I think this is better:**

> 一緒に映画を見たいのです。I want to see a movie with you (together).

The の particle I put in for "explanation" towards the listener. You are trying to explain to them you want to see a movie with them, correct? The particle isn't necessary, it's just my preference.

Note: The sentence I've provided you might not be used if you are asking a good friend (it's kind of formal). In that case you could say:

> 一緒に映画を見たい！I want to see a movie with you!

Answer (score 2):

Japanese does not usually say あなた when you are talking to another person.

> 一緒に映画を見たいです。I want to watch a movie together with you (politely).

But, if that person is your friends or family members, you can just use in 辞書形 by omitting です。

> 一緒に映画を見たい。

Comment: `辞書形` -- You mean 普通形/plain form? (cos 見たい is not the 辞書形/dictionary form of 見る...)

Comment: @Chocolate first example is `ますけい` (Polite form) and the second one is `じしょけい/普通形` (Non-polite form). Polite means you've to use in that form when you are talking to strangers or older people and non-polite means you can only use it to only people close to you.